# Unable to view apache's default index.html file from external IP

Tags: apache

I have set up Apache 2.4 on a server running Ubuntu 14.04.1. I am able to view the default index.html file (the one with the congratulatory message) when I run `w3m http://localhost` but I am not able to connect from an external address using a web browser. I just get the "This webpage is not available" message.

And apache seems to be listening on port 80. When I ran `sudo netstat -ln -p | grep -E ':80'`, I get the following:

`tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      14990/apache2`

I cant seem to figure out what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you access from an external address ? If you don't see a request coming to apache in `access.log` then it should be something which is in front of Apache maybe a firewall ?

Comment: I can SSH into the server from an external IP but cannot access it through the web browser. The `access.log` just mentions the internal requests and has nothing regarding the requests I made from my web browser. When I run `iptables -L`, all connections seem to be open.

Comment: Are you also able to `telnet <server_ip> 80` ? If yes, check your browser settings. If not - then your server still doesn't allow traffic over `port 80`. If you did not check already [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Allowing_Incoming_Traffic_on_Specific_Ports)

Comment: I am able to connect using `telnet`. I have tried using different browsers. I have also tried using `urllib2.urlopen(url)` in python, but I get an error saying "Connection Refused".